# How to write the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table that contains customers (The goal of this table was to be able to add fields without DB-Update). The table looks like this:

```
CustId     Property     PropertyValue  

1          Name         Smith  
1          Email        smith@gmail.com  
2          Name         Donalds  
2          Email        donalds@gmail.com  
3          Name         john
```

(The customer 3 has no entry for "Email" in the table)

**Expected result:** I want to get one line per client (Mail) and if the customer has no email, display still one line with NULL.

```
CustId     Property     PropertyValue  

1          Email        smith@gmail.com  
2          Email        donalds@gmail.com  
3          Email        NULL
```

Has someone the solution ?

Comment: Can you share the SQL you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    CustId INT,
    Property VARCHAR(50),
    PropertyValue VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @t (CustId, Property, PropertyValue)
VALUES
    (1, 'Name', 'Smith'),
    (1, 'Email', 'smith@gmail.com'),
    (2, 'Name', 'Donalds'),
    (2, 'Email', 'donalds@gmail.com'),
    (3, 'Name', 'john')

SELECT CustId
     , Name = 'Email'
     , Value = MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'Email' THEN PropertyValue END)
FROM @t
GROUP BY CustId
```

Comment: Mmm, that's not what he asked for

Comment: Better solution then all of us though:)

Answer (score 5):

**Query 1**

```
Select t1.CustId 
     , ISNULL(t2.Property ,'Email') AS Property 
     , t2.PropertyValue
FROM TableName t1 
LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.CustId = t2.CustId
                      AND t2.Property = 'Email'
WHERE t1.Property = 'Name'
```

**Result Set 1**

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ CustId ║ Property ║   PropertyValue   ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║      1 ║ Email    ║ smith@gmail.com   ║
║      2 ║ Email    ║ donalds@gmail.com ║
║      3 ║ Email    ║ NULL              ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

**Query 2**

Another query for a more readable result set should look something like....

```
Select t1.CustId 
     , t1.PropertyValue [CustomerName]
     , t2.PropertyValue [CustomerEmail]
FROM TableName t1 
LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.CustId = t2.CustId
                      AND t2.Property = 'Email'
WHERE t1.Property = 'Name'
```

**Result Set 2**

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ CustId ║ CustomerName ║   CustomerEmail   ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║      1 ║ Smith        ║ smith@gmail.com   ║
║      2 ║ Donalds      ║ donalds@gmail.com ║
║      3 ║ john         ║ NULL              ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using a derived table containing all possible `ID`'s , and then left joining only to the Emails on the original table:

```
SELECT t.custID,'EMAIL',s.PropertyValue
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT custID
     FROM YourTable) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.custID = s.custID and s.property = 'Email')
```

Can also be done with a correlated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.CustID,'EMAIL',
       (SELECT s.PropertyValue
        FROM YourTable s
        WHERE s.custID = t.custID and s.Property = 'Email')
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: Your first query results in the following error: `Invalid column name 'property'.`

Your second query works as intended.

Comment: @HappyCoding Thanks, typo. Mixed `s` with `t`

Answer (score 1):

Self join with same table, property passed via variable

```
DECLARE @prop nvarchar(max) = 'Email'

SELECT DISTINCT c.CustId, @prop as Property, c1.PropertyValue
FROM yourtable c 
LEFT JOIN yourtable c1
    ON c.CustId = c1.CustId and c1.Property = @prop
```

Output will be as you posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustId
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Property IS NULL THEN 'Email' ELSE Property END) Property
     , MIN(PropertyValue) PropertyValue
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CustId
HAVING Property = 'Email';
```

Comment: What does this add to the other answers?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This query filter the row which has the property value  is 'Email' and also group the cust id. So if any custid has no 'Email' as property value, it return as null.